# Doxygen does not parse __attribute__ correctly

Tags: c, attributes, doxygen

I have some functions defined the following way:

```
 * @brief   Obtains the current time tick of the OS.
 *          This is a weak function and is intended to be overridden.
 * @return  In the weak version always 0. Otherwise should return the current
 *          OS time tick.
 */
__attribute__((__weak__)) osalUint_t osal_tickGetCurrent(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

They are defined as "weak". When I generate the doxygen output for a c file with such a definition, the function is not parsed correctly.

[image]

Is there a way to make the Doxygen be `__attribute__` aware when it comes to functions (and other objects too, such as structs)?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? I think the solution of the problem is described in the documentation: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

Comment: The latest downloaded right now. I tried the solution you have suggested but it does not work, or I don't understand how should the `PREDEFINED` be assigned for this specific case.

Comment: Latest is a moving target, so please specify the version (probably it is 1.9.6). I think the example shows quite well what to do, so e.g. `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES\n
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES\n
PREDEFINED             = __attribute__(x)=`. (had to use `\=n` to signal line breaks as comments here cannot have line breaks). When this does not solve your issue please add the result of the command `doxygen -x Doxyfile` to the question.

Comment: Or did I miss something,  do you want to have some extra text somewhere? In the later case please indicate which text you would like to see and where it should be.

Comment: I am using 1.9.6. I have set the values exactly like you- it does not work.  Output: https://pastebin.com/K30Fsnai my doxyfile: https://pastebin.com/tzQ2szGn

Comment: Please don't place the files on pastebin as this is an external reference (I won't look at it)  and might not be persistent, please add the information to the question.

Comment: Ok, it worked. It seems that Doxygen refixed to parse that part of the code, because of some other issues he has found prior to that (unrelated, but still, probably did not get to that part).

Comment: Indeed most likely the cause of the problem. What is the first issue you found (probably best in a new question when the solution is not directly clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used as source code:

```
/// \file

/**
 * @brief   Obtains the current time tick of the OS.
 *          This is a weak function and is intended to be overridden.
 * @return  In the weak version always 0. Otherwise should return the current
 *          OS time tick.
 */
__attribute__((__weak__)) osalUint_t osal_tickGetCurrent(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

And as doxygen settings file (Doxyfile):

```
QUIET = YES
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
PREDEFINED             = __attribute__(x)=
```

and the result is:

[image]