# doxygen interprets __attribute__ as not documented return parameter

Tags: c++, doxygen

I use doxygen@1.9.5 for c++ code documentation.

I have an expression

```
constexpr __attribute__((always_inline)) MyClass() = default;
```

and doxygen reports

```
return type of member MyClass::__attribute__ is not documented
```

Is there a solution to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doxygen does not parse \_\_attribute\_\_ correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75410662/doxygen-does-not-parse-attribute-correctly)  and there are more questions regarding this topic. See also https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

Comment: Yes, it answers my question.